# Arch Linux - Get time offset for all timezones

Tags: linux, time-zone

I am using `Arch` Linux `timedatectl list-timezones` command to retrieve the list of time zones. I would like to get the time difference i.e. offset (from `UTC`/`GMT`) for each time zone.

For example:

`Asia/Kolkata +05:30`

`Asia/Singapore +08:00`

Is there any `systemctl` command that would help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **date** command to figure the timezone offset from the name using the **TZ** environment variable.  Here's a quick shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Timezones and current offsets
ZONES="$(timedatectl list-timezones)"

for ZONE in $ZONES
do
    OFFSET="$(env TZ=${ZONE} date +%:z)"
    echo "$ZONE $OFFSET"
done
```